# Randomize and display sprites in a 4x6 grid - Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am creating a card matching game. I have a vector that stores 16 unique cards. I am trying to randomize the order and select only the first 12 cards, then setup in a 4x6 grid for a total of 24 matching pairs. I'm having trouble randomizing it and displaying it in the grid. Also, I am using Cocos2d-x 3.2. Thanks for any advice.

```
std::vector<Sprite*> cards;
std::vector<std::string> cardNames = { "0.png", "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png", "10.png", "11.png", "12.png", "13.png", "14.png", "15.png" };

for (int n = 0; n < cardNames.size(); n++)
{
    auto sprite = Sprite::create(cardNames.at(n));

    sprite->setPosition(cocos2d::Point((50 * (n + 1)), 20));
    sprite->setTag(n);

    cards.push_back(sprite);

    addChild(sprite);
}

std::random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end());

for (int n = 0; n <= 11; n++) // select forst 12 cards to display in the grid
{
    // logic to create grid
    // set position of each card

    addChild(cards); // error here
}
```

Comment: Probably you wrote addChild(cards) as an example? You should use addChild(cards.at(n))

Answer (score 1):

To do random numbers in C++ you need to 
`#include <random>` and `#include<time.h>` then create a seed using:

```
srand(time(NULL))
```

Then you must create a random number like so.

```
int randNum = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

This will create a random number in the range of 0-9 but then we add 1 and it will be somewhere between 1-10.

Keep in mind it's not the only way to generate a random number.

As for your program just assign all the the cards a number, then create another array of random numbers, and those will be your random positions in the vector. (Don't forget to prevent repeats.)